# Proof that this specific function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, self-learning

**Bounty Edit:**  Considering the nature of the problem at hand (i.e. proving that a specific function is measurable), I think this can be an easy but relevant problem. In particular, it is relevant to me, because I am at loss when dealing with this kind of problems, that move from the abstract setting of a book, to a concrete setting given by a specific example.

---

Here there is the setup of my problem:

- measurable $\ g: (X, \Sigma_X) \to (Y, \Sigma_Y)$;
- the *image measure* $$\hat{g} : (\Delta (X), \Sigma_{\Delta(X)}) \to (\Delta (Y), \Sigma_{\Delta(Y)})\hspace{0.5cm} \text{such that} \hspace{0.5cm} \forall E \in \Sigma_Y, \ \hat{g} ( \pi) (E) = \pi \circ g^{-1} (E),$$
  where $\Delta (X)$ (resp. $\Delta (Y)$) is the set of all probability measures over $X$ (resp. $Y$), and $\Sigma_{\Delta(\cdot)}$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra of the corresponding set in the subscript, generated by sets of the form $\beta^{p} (E) := \{ \mu \in \Delta (Y) \ | \ \mu (E) \geq p \}$, or $\delta^{p} (F) := \{ \pi \in \Delta (X) \ | \ \pi (F) \geq p \} $,  for arbitrary sets $E \in \Sigma_Y$ and $F \in \Sigma_X$.

In general, I denote measures in $\Delta (X)$ with $\pi$, and measures in $\Delta (Y)$ with $\mu$.

> **Proposition:** $\hat{g}$ is measurable.
>
> ***Attempted proof:*** This amounts at proving that, for every $E \in \Sigma_Y$, $\hat{g}^{-1} ( \beta^p (E) ) \subseteq \Sigma_{\Delta(X)}$, that is the same as proving that there is a $F \in \Sigma_X$ such that $g(F) = E$, and $\hat{g} ( \delta^p (F) ) = \beta^p (E)$. Notice that the definition of *image measure* implies that, for every $E \in \Sigma_Y$, there is a $F \in \Sigma_X$ such that $g(F) =E$ and $\mu (E) \equiv \hat{g} (\pi) (E) = \pi \circ g^{-1} (E) \equiv \pi (F)$ **(Right?)**. Thus, we simply have to prove that $\hat{g} ( \delta^p (F)) = \beta^p (E)$.
> To establish the result, the following chain of biconditionals works:
> $$ \hat{g} ( \delta^p (F)) \Longleftrightarrow \forall \pi \in \delta^p (F) \ \exists \mu \in \beta^p (g(F)) \Longleftrightarrow \exists \mu \in \beta^p (E) \Longleftrightarrow \beta^p (E). $$
> $\square$

I am wondering if the result and my line of reasoning are correct, because I really have problems in seeing exactly what I have to do to concretely to prove that a specific function is measurable.

Any help or feedback is most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: To the moderators: I added the "proof strategy" tag, because I am also asking if – *in general* – this is the correct approach to attack this kind of results.

Comment: Where did you get this from?

Comment: What's your definition of $\Delta(X)$?

Comment: @roy_24601: see my edit to get the answer, but basically it denotes the set of all probability measures over a given space.

Comment: The leftmost and the rightmost in the chain of implication are not statements. They are just sets. If you are after a rigorous proof, you need to fix that first. Your idea might be right, but you have to write it in a correct way.

Comment: I assume from your answer that my basic remark is correct, and I am glad to read it. :) . Regarding the chain of biconditionals, I don't see what should be the problem about the fact that I start with sets: considering I want to prove that $\hat{g} ( \delta^p (F)) = \beta^p (E)$, my idea was to follow the lines of a standard proof of a result like $f^{-1} ( \bigcup_{i \in I} B_i ) =  \bigcup_{i \in I} f^{-1} ( B_i )$, where you start on LHS with the original set assumption we take, and then we go on with "$f(x) \in \bigcup_{i \in I} B_i$" and so on. Is it really that sloppy my formulation?

Comment: Btw, thanks a lot for your comments and answers. Truly extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make sense of the question, one needs $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$, two $\sigma$-algebras on $X$ and $Y$ to talk about $g$ being measurable. Now assume $g\colon (X, \sigma(X)) \to (Y, \sigma(Y))$ is measurable.

Also, I believe $\Delta(X)$ and $\Delta(Y)$ are sets of probability measures with respect to $(X, \sigma(X))$ and $Y, \sigma(Y)$. And $\Sigma_X$ should be generated by $$\{\pi\in\Delta(X):\pi(F)\ge p\},\text{ where }F\in\sigma(X)\text{ and }p\in\mathbb{R},$$ and $\Sigma_Y$ should be modified likewise.

In order to show the proposition, we need:

**Claim** For $F\in \sigma(Y)$ and $p\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $$\cup\{\hat{g}^{-1}(\mu) : \mu\in\Delta(Y), \mu(F)\ge p\} = \{\pi \in \Delta(X):\pi(g^{-1}(F)) \ge p\}.$$

**Proof of Claim**

First of all, we show LHS $\subset$ RHS. Pick $\pi\in$ LHS, that is $\pi \in \hat{g}^{-1}(\mu)$ for some $\mu\in\Delta(Y)$ such that $\mu(F)\ge p$. Then $\mu = \hat{g}(\pi)$, and so $\mu(F') = \pi\circ g^{-1}(F')$ for all $F' \in \sigma(Y)$. In particular, $\pi(g^{-1}(F)) = \mu(F)\ge p$, hence $\pi\in$ RHS.

Secondly, we show RHS$\subset$LHS. If $\pi\in$ RHS, that is, $\pi\in\Delta(X)$ and $\pi(g^{-1}(F))\ge p$, then $\mu: Y\to[0,1]$ defined by $\mu(F') = \pi\circ g^{-1}(F')$ for all $F'\in \sigma(Y)$ is indeed a probability measure on $(Y, \sigma(Y))$, namely $\mu\in\Delta(Y)$. Moreover, since $\mu(F)=\pi\circ g^{-1}(F) \ge p$ and $\mu=\hat{g}(\pi)$ (by definition of $\mu$), we know that $\pi\in$ LHS.

**Consequence of Claim**

In the claim, LHS is the inverse image of a generating element of $\Sigma_Y$ and RHS is a generating element of $\Sigma_X$ since $g^{-1}(F)\in\sigma(X)$. $\hat{g}$ is therefore measurable.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your detailed answer. May I ask you more specifically if there is something wrong in my proof, and – if this is the case – if this can be fix, saving the overall structure of the proof? Indeed, my main concern behind the bounty was to actually now if my attempted proof was correct. Getting the proof of the result, in case my attempted proof was wrong, was just a minor point behind the bounty.

Comment: The problem I have with your question is that it doesn't specify the $\sigma$-algebras of $X$ and $Y$, which made me realized that in lieu of these additional structure, couple of things in the questions are ill-defined. What you might want to do is to read the first two paragraphs of my answer and redo/re-examine your proof.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. As you probably noticed, by writing in the original answer that $g$ was measurable, and by always writing $E \subseteq Y$, I had implicitly endowed $X$ and $Y$ with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra. Anyway, now I made your point explicit in the proof. However, this leaves unsolved a couple of questions particularly relevant to me.

Comment: **1.** Is actually true – as I write – that "*the definition of 'image measure' implies that, for every $E \in \Sigma_Y$, there is a $F \in \Sigma_X$ such that $g(F) =E$ and $\mu (E) \equiv \hat{g} (\pi) (E) = \pi \circ g^{-1} (E) \equiv \pi (F)$*"? I ask this, because basically my entire proof relies on this remark.

Comment: **2.** Is the last chain of implications correct?

Comment: **3.** Is the overall strategy behind the proof correct?

Comment: I stress those questions simply because they were the main driving forces behind the bounty.